React Component Collapsing Issue: Ref Not Initialized During URL Parsing
I have a component that should expand if it is selected. Here's my current approach:
<Element 
   ref={elementRef}
   style={{ height: isSelected ? `${elementRef.current.scrollHeight}px` : '0px' }} 
/>

Now, I've added routing, which parses the URL. For example, if I am at host:port/selected/1, the first element should automatically expand.
The URL parsing works fine, but it happens just at the beginning of the creation of the website.
This results that while the function is returning the JSX-Element, isSelected evaluates to true which causes an issue because the ref has not yet been initialized. (elementRef.current is null)
Or to put it in different words: the scrollHeight of a non-rendered object doesn't make sense and React tells me so.
I'm struggling to figure out the best way to handle this. I think I need to use a different hook than useRef, but which one?
I tried using useState with the dependencies isSelected and elementRef which is not fired after rendering, but before (or during).

I managed to fix it by using useCallback
So instead of
<Element 
   ref={elementRef}
   style={{ height: isSelected ? `${elementRef.current.scrollHeight}px` : '0px' }} 
/>

I have achieved it by using the useCallback hook which is called after each rendering pass:
const detailRef = useCallback((element) => {
  if (!element) {
    return;
  }

  element.style.height = isExpanded ? `${element.scrollHeight}px` : '0px';
}, [isExpanded]);

// ...

return (
<Element ref={detailRef} />
);



If the ref is not set yet on the very initial render then you can likely use the Optional Chaining operator and a fallback value.
Example:
<Element 
   ref={elementRef}
   style={{
     height: isSelected
       ? `${elementRef.current?.scrollHeight ?? 0}px`
       : '0px'
   }} 
/>


While this prevents the App from crashing it isn't this solution rather unsafe? It can at least result in the component not expanded even tho it should because of a timing-problem. Or do I have a misunderstanding?

@BingBang I don't believe it to be unsafe. What is the concern here regarding safety?

Sorry I pressed enter and it send the comment, I wanted a line-break. I have edited the comment meanwhile and explained a little further.

@BingBang No worries. I don't suspect there'd be any "timing issues" unless isSelected isn't some React state or is being mutated somehow. If you need more help can you edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] so it's easier for readers to more fully understand what your code is trying to accomplish.

Well the fallback is to not expand the Element. In case isSelected is false it just doesn't expand and thats it. Well it doesnt crash but it still is broken. I have the feeling I need some kind of callback on when the rendering finished so I can expand it then.

@BingBang The fallback can be any value you think is a safe value to use. It could 50px or 100px, for example, if those are safe defaults that make sense for your UI. Seeing a more complete [mcve] would help inform what a good default/fallback value could be, or how to better handle the possibly null React ref.

FYI I managed to fix it using useCallback. I just added an according answer
